# .NET & ESMTP Postfix Email Tracking

Tags: .net, email, tracking

Is there any way to track emails (Delivery status or/and Read Status) in .NET application (C# language) sent using ESMTP Postfix mail server?

Comment: You mean confirm delivery, or just process bounces, or process read-receipts, or something like that? Do you just want to parse / query the ESMTP logs, or something more? (I'm not sure there's any more you can achieve though without more access to the recipient system.)

Comment: Delivery status or/and Read Status. But I'm wondering if it's even possible!? Thanks.

Comment: Postfix logs will tell you when and to where a message left your system. Beyond that, it's bounce messages for non-delivery tracking (somewhat unreliable) and/or web beacons in your messages to track read rates (highly unreliable).

Comment: But can postfix log tell me that the message had been successfully delivered to the server (not the person so maybe than it was put to spam but the recipients' server got the email)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the message to add a unique tracking pixel.  With posfix you can use altermime to modify the actual mime message.  Its a complex and dirty process.  You can also configure amavisd to do this sort of work by modifying its disclaimer code.

If you are simply trying to track email delivery and email I highly recommend taking a look at mailgun.  The folks at maigun have done a superb job building this type of functionality into their product.  You can use them as an SMTP relay, or use their rest api to shoot out emails.
They allow you to add extra headers, and track emails automaticaly.  best of all they have hook urls where they post events for read, and others.